# Kendo tooltip for React not displaying correctly on links under LI elements

Tags: kendo-react-ui

I'm running into issues trying to display the Kendo React tooltip correctly on certain elements.

The tooltip renders correctly on [anchor] elements and [list item] elements just fine, however if it's an [anchor] inside a [list item] then it no longer displays and reverts back to a standard tooltip.

I've replicated it using a Stackblitz as it's easier seen than explained

https://react-e5gq87.stackblitz.io

Can anyone see why this is acting the way it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to fix this is add parentTitle={true} to your  element.

It's the span that is breaking the functionality